# Converting arraylist to JSON

Tags: android, arrays, json, servlets, arraylist

I have an android activity that receives an arraylist from a servlet. Example [stl1010, P3]. When I try to convert this to JSON Object (using the parser class) I get the exception **"Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value ["stl1010","P3"] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject."** Below is the servlet code:

```
private ArrayList<String> ticketLookup(String tkt)
  {
    Connection con = null;
    Statement st = null;
    //StringArray msga = new StringArray();
    ArrayList<String> msga = new ArrayList();

    try
    {
      // These will vary depending on your server/database      
      Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");  
      con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://serveripaddr;databaseName=dbname;user=sa;password=pwd");
      Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select status,description,priority,openingdate,closeddate,assigned_to,resolvergroup,assigneddatel1,impactedbyuser,emailid from ServiceRequest where TicketNo = '"+tkt+"'");
 while (rs.next())
      {

//          rs.getString(2);
          msga.add(String.valueOf(rs.getString("assigned_to")));
          msga.add(String.valueOf(rs.getString("priority")));
     }
      //JSONArray mJSONArray = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(mStringArray));    
      return msga;
```

Below is the code from my android app (JSON Parser class + activity). Activity code:

```
public void addListenerOnGoButton(){
btnGo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()

{
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/GnP22/GetNpostServlet?TicketNo="+etTkt.getText();
        String TAG_TICKET = "ticket";
        String TAG_STATUS = "status";
        String TAG_DESC = "description";
        String TAG_PRIORITY = "priority";
        String TAG_OPENDATE = "openingdate";
        String TAG_CLOSEDATE = "closingdate";
        String TAG_ASSIGNEDTO = "assignedto";
        String TAG_RESOLVERGROUP = "resolvergroup";
        String TAG_ASSIGNEDDATEL1 = "assigneddatel1";
        String TAG_IMPACTEDUSER = "impactedbyuser";
        String TAG_EMAILID = "emailid";

        // contacts JSONArray
        JSONArray contacts = null;

        // Creating JSON Parser instance
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        try {
            // Getting Array of Contacts
            contacts = json.getJSONArray(TAG_TICKET);
            for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(0);

            String status = c.getString(TAG_STATUS);
            String description = c.getString(TAG_DESC);
            //String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
            //String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
            //String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);
            tvStatus.setText(status);
            tvDescription.setText(description);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("JSON Exception", e.toString());
        }
}
});

}
```

Below is the code for JSON Parser class:

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

 // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            //HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Comment: Well, if you know that you're sending a JSONArray from the server, why not simply parse it as an array on the client?  Instead of `JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(json)`, you'd do `JSONArray jArr = new JSONArray(json)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an array in response where as you are trying to get an object

Replace

```
// getting JSON string from URL
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
```

to

```
JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
```

Also

```
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
    //This returns a JSONObject Modify this to return JSONArray
}
```

Comment: Thanks that has worked. I have directly called the strings from the JSONArray.