# Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Unterminated array at character

Tags: android, arrays, json, servlets, arraylist

I am new to JSON and am not aware of the constraints that need to be followed for an Arraylist to successfully convert to a JSONArray. I am trying to send an arraylist of multiple string elements from a servlet to a JSON Parser. The same works when I have small elements e.g. [Resolved, Working] but my JSON Parser class throws an error if an array element contains spaces or special characters. I get the below error while parsing:

```
08-20 16:46:13.480: E/JSON Parser(475): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Unterminated array at character 17 of [Closed, Emails not working in A-82 premises ; Requested Username: P Smith]
```

JSON Parser code:

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONArray jArr = null;
    static String json = "";

 // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONArray getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            //HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jArr = new JSONArray(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jArr;

    }
}
```

Comment: Use an online JSON validator to validate your JSON and respond if everything is ok, after that we'll check for further errors

Comment: How to I generate JSON of an arraylist so that I can run it through the validator?

Comment: In the code above you are retrieving the JSON from a Url. This JSON you have to validate

Comment: Using above example if array = [Resolved,Working] then JSONArray = ["Resolved","Working"] which is good. But if array = [Closed, Emails not working] then JSONArray returns as null. I do not get a suitable JSONArray to pass through validator.

Comment: Validate the JSON you get directly from your service before you touch it in order to see if the JSON is correct. Not JSON > Android > Array > Json > validator. Instead do Service > JSON > JSON Validator.

Comment: As my string contains blank spaces and new lines the JSON is not returned from the service. I read somewhere that JSON requires new lines to be escaped properly. How do we do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a sample call that i have (just needs to be wrapped in a try-catch):

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(URLProcessing.GetUrl(path));
```

i keep this in a Utils class:

```
public static String GetUrl(String url) throws Exception {
    URL serverAddress = null;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    BufferedReader rd = null;
    StringBuilder sb = null;
    String line = null;

    try {
        serverAddress = new URL(url);
        // set up out communications stuff
        connection = null;
        // Set up the initial connection
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) serverAddress.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setReadTimeout(15000);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        connection.connect();

        // read the result from the server
        rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        sb = new StringBuilder();

        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
        // Swallow
    } finally {
        // close the connection, set all objects
        // to null
        connection.disconnect();
        rd = null;
        sb = null;
        connection = null;
    }
}
```

if any of this breaks for you then i'd say you have some broken JSON that you should grab and throw in to a website like http://jsonlint.com/ to see what's going on... i've been using this code for over a year now without issue.

Comment: I am still getting the above exception after using the code provided by you above. It also gives me a whole bunch of "com.facebook.katana" exceptions. Is there some library you use that yI have not added? For some reason elements without spaces are successfully surrounded with "" but any space and the JSONArray fails to surround the element with "".

Comment: I read somewhere that JSON requires new lines to be escaped properly. How do we do that?

Comment: My problem occurs for both: new lines and spaces

Comment: can you post an example of a url that returns some JSON that you're trying to parse? is this something that you're generating on the server side? it sounds like you have some bad json. i dont think those facebook exceptions have anything to do with this.

Comment: The URL does not return JSON, it returns an array. The array is being converted to JSON in my android app using a JSON Parser class. I have a server side web-service (servlet) that returns an array in the format: [Resolved, Email not working]. When I convert this using the JSON Parser class then I get the error: org.json.JSONException: Unterminated array at character 17 --> This changes as per occurence of the space or new line.

Comment: [Resolved, Email not working] is not valid json, and not a valid json array... if that is what you're feeding in to the json parser then please provide an example of what you're expecting this json parser to output.

Comment: here is an example of a json array with two elements: [{"countryCode":"US", "countryName":"United States of America"},
{"countryCode":"AD", "countryName":"Andorra"}]. json is made up of keys and values, both of which need to be wrapped in quotes. it sounds like you're trying to send an array of strings and parse it as json

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Is ["Resolved","Email"] valid JSON? Because JSONLint says it is and the parser im using above gives me this as output for the array [Resolved,Email]. Same thing fails for [Resolved, Email not working].

Comment: it is valid in the sense that it is an array of two strings. that is very limiting. in my eyes the more correct way of going about things is to have a JSONArray of JSONObjects.in each object would be whatever constant fields with whatever for the values. you would access each jsonobject in the array and then access the value for the given key in each object. here is an example: [ {"state": "resolved", "type": "email"}, {"state": "not working", "type": "email"} ]. i'm not necessarily interpreting your data correctly but i think you should get the idea from that

Comment: Do I need to create a JSONArray of JSONObjects only? I thought we could create a JSONArray of string elements.  I was told we could use the string array as input for JSON parser in my earlier post here:     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18331193/converting-arraylist-to-json Will it be better if my response from server side is a JSONArray containing JSONObjects?

Comment: Also why does it get stuck only at spaces and new lines?

Comment: I am now sending this:- [{"status":"Closed","description":"Email is not working"}] from my servlet. Is this a JSONArray or a JSONObject? How can we parse this in android and display the status and description values in textviews?

Comment: that is a json array containing a single json object which in turn contains two key/value pairs. the reason you're getting errors when you have spaces and such is because they need to be wrapped in quotes. you can do anything you want, but having an array of json objects is much more scalable then an array of strings.

Comment: Ok. So how do i go about putting the value of status in a tvStatus and description in tvDescription?

Comment: I was able to pull the elements from the JSONArray and display them in their respective text views. I needed to access them via a JSONObject. Thanks for all the help :)